# how to write enum with manual decoding

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have a json response which is something like this:

```
"Details": {
        "Attachments": [],
        "place": {
          "destination": {
            "type": "international",
            "Id": "superman",
            "locationType": "City",
            "Name": "Kent"
          },
          "package": 52.32,
          "description": "Dinner"
        }
      }
    }
```

in this response all the parameters in destination are optional except for type, so i m handling this response like this:

```
public struct Destination: Decodable, Equatable {
    public let Id: String?
    public let Name: String?
    public let city: String?
    public let locationType: String?
    public let pinCode: String?
    public let country: String?
    public let state: String?
    public let currency: String?
    public let language: String?
    public let type: Type
}
```

as all the parameters are optional and based upto the type i ll be getting only few of these parameters in response.
like -

```
type: "international",
       country: "US"
       id: "5",
       currency: "Dollar"
```

is there any way i can write this in an enum:

```
enum Destination {
case international(country: String, id: String, currency: String)
case national(state: String, language: String, pincode: String)
}
```

can anyone please answer how should i start with this approach.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Swift 5.5 enums with associated values have [Codable synthesis](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0295-codable-synthesis-for-enums-with-associated-values.md#codable-synthesis-for-enums-with-associated-values), but this requires the top-level container to contain a single key that matches the name of the enum case. In your case you what a value inside the container to determine the case, so the only solution is to write the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` yourself, decode all the associated values and then return the enum value.

Something like this would work:

```
public struct Place: Decodable {
    var destination: Destination
}

enum Destination: Decodable {
    case international(country: String?, Id: String?, currency: String?)
    case national(state: String?, language: String?, pincode: String?)

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
        case country
        case Id
        case currency
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        let country = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .country)
        let Id = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .Id)
        let currency = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .currency)

        switch type {
        case "international":
            self = Destination.international(country: country, Id: Id, currency: currency)
        case "national":
            fatalError("not supported yet")
            () // similary
        default:
            fatalError("not supported yet")
            () // throw an decoding error
        }
    }
}
```

The above would work with the JSON you have provided:

```
let json = """ {
        "destination": {
            "type": "international",
            "Id": "superman",
            "country": "City",
            "currency": "Kent"
        } } """ 

    do {
         let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Place.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!) 
   } 
   catch {
         print("error \(error)") 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @Christos Koninis , let me try it out

Answer (score 0):

**you have to write enum such as**

```
Enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case Id, Name, city, locationType, pinCode, country, state, currency, language = String?

    case type = Type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Details: Decodable {

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case Attachments, place
  }

  let Attachments: Array?
    let place: Place?

}

struct Place: Decodable {
  let destination: Destination?
    let package: Double?
    let description: String?
}

struct Destination: Decodable {
  let type, Id, locationType, Name: String?
}
```

Comment: Please give some context how this is a useful answer.